# Find Limit of a Sequence without an Explicit Formula

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $x_{1} = 1.5$ and $x_{n + 1} = x_{n}/2 + 1/x_{n}$. The limit of $\left\{x_{n}\right\}$ is sought.

If the limit of $\left\{x_{n}\right\}$ exists, then
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1} = \left(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n}\right)/2 + 1/\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n},
\end{equation}
if we assume that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n} \neq 0$. Let $s = \lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n}$, and the above equation can be turned into
\begin{equation}
s = s / 2 + 1 / s,
\end{equation}
and $s = \sqrt{2}$.

All this process only indicates that if the limit exists and is nonzero, then it is equal to $\sqrt{2}$. How should I verify that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n} = \sqrt{2}$?

Comment: The proof is already correct. You can verify that by using the fact from the first equation that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n+1}$ and inserting the recursive formula - which will yield $\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{2}$

Comment: Hint : by studying the function $f(x) = x/2 + 1/x$, prove that $\sqrt{2} \leq x_{n+1} \leq x_n$.

Comment: @LegNaiB The above does not prove the existence of the limit.

Comment: That's correct. However, is there an example, where you will get a limit by using above calculation but the limit doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asuume $x_1=\frac 32$. convert the recurrence formula,
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}-\sqrt{2}&=\frac 1{2x_n}(x_n-\sqrt{2})^2.
\end{align}
Therefore, if $\sqrt{2}<x_n$, then $\sqrt{2}<x_{n+1}$, and we have,
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}-\sqrt{2}&<(x_n-\sqrt{2})^2\\
&<(x_{n-1}-\sqrt{2})^4\\
&<\cdots\\
&<(x_1-\sqrt{2})^{2^n}.\\
&<\frac{1}{2^{2^n}}
\end{align}
Hence,
$$
0\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n-\sqrt{2})\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1{2^{2^{n-1}}}=0
$$

Comment: Lower and upper error bounds lead to the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a monotonic decay condition:
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n}{2}+\frac{1}{x_n}=\frac{x_n^2+2}{2x_n}$$
$$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=\frac{x_n^2+2}{2x_n^2}<1$$
$$0<x_n^2-2 \implies x_n > \sqrt{2}, \,x_n < -\sqrt{2}$$
Now let us check that $x_{n+1} > \sqrt{2}$ if $x_n > \sqrt{2}$
$$x_{n+1} =  \frac{x_n^2+2}{2x_n} > \sqrt{2}$$
$$x_n^2-2\sqrt{2}x_n+2 > 0 \implies \textrm{true }\forall x_n > \sqrt{2}$$
So we have that, since $x_1=1.5$, the sequence is monotonically decreasing with lower bound $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Assume that a sequence is monotonically decreasing with an error bound $s$, and if the limit of the sequence exists, the limit is $s$. Do the two conditions ensure that the limit of the sequence is $s$?

Comment: @ZiqiFan Monotone convergence and lower bound > 0 ensure that the limit exists and is >0, thus justifying what you wrote in the OP